# Make responsive design for device type with Bootstrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I got a web site on which it is possible to upload a file with an activation code and an `input` to insert it via hand. On smartphones and tablets the `fileupload` should not be possible. I try it like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

        <title />

        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Some content for the page -->

        <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
            <span>Upload file</span>

            <input type="file" />
            <input type="button" value="Upload" />
        </div>

        <div>
            <span>Insert key</span>

            <input type="text" />
        </div>

        <!-- More content for the page -->
    </body>
</html>
```

This works fine on Smartphones, Tablets in portrait mode and on Desktop. On Tablets in landscape mode the upload is visible. The resolution seems to be for "medium" (which meens Desktop) and so it is shown.

Is it possible to get an info if the device is a Smartphone, Tablet or Desktop and define the behaviour for each?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not use `@media` query and set width so it doesn't show if the screen size is bigger than the provided width

Comment: You could try using Modernizr to check if the device is a touch device or not.

Comment: Are you using media queries other than those provided by Bootstrap? Its unclear what you've tried with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to determine the useragent for that, which is not possible with CSS only.
You could use Javascript to add a certain body class, or something on the server side.

There's a lot of scripts on [detectmobilebrowser.com](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/), which you can modify to differentiate between smartphones and tablets, for example.